# how to let cakephp paginator go to the last page, when user input a page number is bigger than max page (overflow)?

Tags: cakephp

let say I have 21 records

my view shows 10 records per page

and now i am on page:3, and then I delete a record and refresh the page

cake will show a not found error

how can I go to page 2(last page), instead of showing a error message ?

---

I checked the PaginatorComponent.php
it just throw a NotFoundException

```
if ($requestedPage > $page) {
            throw new NotFoundException();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

according to the [Manual](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/pagination.html#out-of-range-page-requests) you have to catch the exception and redirect to the right page

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did although I'm not necessarily happy with it.

```
    try {
        $this->Paginator->settings = $this->paginate;
        $widgets = $this->paginate();
    } catch (NotFoundException $e) {
        //Redirect to previous page
        $query = $this->request->query;
        $query['page']--;
        extract(Router::parse($this->request->here)); 
        $pass = empty($pass) ? '' : $pass[0]; 
        $this->redirect(array_merge(array('action' => $action, $pass), array('?' => $query))); 
    }
```

As you can see I decrement the page number in the query string and keep redirecting that until I reach a valid page. I was unable to find the known number of pages to just direct to the last page. Also, I'm not happy with extracting the parts of the URL just to rebuild it.  In my case the $pass param may or may not exist which is why I do the empty check. Although this works, I'd welcome ideas on how to do it better.

Comment: The number of pages is available in `$this->request->params['paging']` when called after $this->paginate(), however, since $this->paginate() is executed in a try block, the result of `$this->request->params['paging']` is not available in the catch block.  Suggestions on how to do this right or better appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

What I did was to get the previous page when catching the NoFoundException, but via the named params:

```
try {
    $records = $this->Paginator->paginate();
} catch (NotFoundException $e) {
    $this->request->params['named']['page']--;
    $records = $this->Paginator->paginate();
}
```

I think it would be better to just overwrite the paginator component, though.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```php
class PaginatorComponent extends CorePaginatorComponent
{

```
/**
 * Overwrite to always redirect from out of bounds to last page of paginated collection.
 * If pageCount not available, then use first page.
 *
 * @param \Cake\Datasource\RepositoryInterface|\Cake\Datasource\QueryInterface $object The table or query to paginate.
 * @param array $settings The settings/configuration used for pagination.
 *
 * @throws \Cake\Network\Exception\NotFoundException
 *
 * @return \Cake\Datasource\ResultSetInterface Query results
 */
public function paginate($object, array $settings = [])
{
    try {
        $resultSet = parent::paginate($object, $settings);
    } catch (NotFoundException $exception) {
        $query = null;
        if ($object instanceof QueryInterface) {
            $query = $object;
            $object = $query->repository();
        }
        $alias = $object->alias();
        $lastPage = $this->request->params['paging'][$alias]['pageCount'] > 1 ? $this->request->params['paging'][$alias]['pageCount'] : null;

        $response = $this->getController()->redirect(['?' => ['page' => $lastPage] + $this->request->getQuery()]);

        // To be please PHPCS and tests, cannot be reached in production.
        if (PHP_SAPI === 'cli') {
            throw new NotFoundException('Redirect to ' . $response->getHeaderLine('Location') . ' for non-CLI.');
        } else {
            $response->send();
        }

        exit();
    }

    return $resultSet;
}
```

}
```

Just put that in your project, it will automatically be used instead of the core one.
Works for <=3.4 (First page) and 3.5+ (Last page).

Answer (score 0):

Use a try-catch for pagination and redirect to initial page.

```
    try {
      $videos = $this->paginate($videos, $paginate);
    } catch (NotFoundException $e) { // Not existing page
      return $this->redirect([ // Remove pagination
        "controller" => $this->request->getParam('controller'),
        "action" => $this->request->getParam('action'),
      ]);
    }
```

For redirecting to last page, then see answer from @Kris.